# Логика начисление процентов каждый день mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Я не могу понять логику начисление процентов.
Есть сумма, которую например человек положил. 
Каждый день ему должно зачислятся 2.5% 
Например, он положил 200 рублей, ровно через день, должны прийти 5 рублей. 
Я конечно может быть понимаю как это делать. Например человек хочет посмотреть сколько уже у него зачислилось, и отправляет запрос в базу данных. **Перед тем как он положил сумму, записалась дата пополнения.** Берем эту дату, сравниваем с текущей, и (`Текущая дата - Дата пополнения` = `часы`); Узнаю разницу в часах, и например уже `34ч`, т.е уже прошло 34 часа, после пополнения, прошел уже 1 день. **Узнаю день:** `34 / 24 = 1,41`, округляю получается `1` день, значит будет одно зачисление. Как узнать что прошел уже второй день? Не знаю честно. Может быть записывать в `бд` количество зачислений. И например, уже прошло 48 часов, `48 / 24` = 2. Видим в бд `1` день уже зачислен. 2 - 1 = `1`, опять `1` раз зачисляем. Если там уже `96 / 24` = `4`, в бд уже видим `2`, а прошло уже как 4 дня. `4 - 2 = 2`, значит 2 раза зачисляем ему на баланс. Или можно как то обновлять дату.

---

### Вопросы:

1. Проблема в том, если пользователь опять пополнит сумму. Как это тогда? Обновлять дату или нет?
2. Как сделать так, что бы смотреть баланс не за день, а например за секунды, т.е в течение дня должно быть + 2.5%.
3. Есть ли другая логика или другие способы?

*Я понимаю, это сделать легко, но я думаю мне из-за своих идей нужно возится и есть какие то подводные камни. Не могли бы вы предложить свой способ?*

Comment: При начислении процентов время как бы не учитывается. Учитывается только количество полных суток. Впрочем, ты себе можешь придумать всё, что угодно...

Comment: *Каждый день ему должно зачислятся 2.5%* - вы для кого прогу пишете, я бы положил :)